# selenium clicking button in google translate with Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I'm trying to use selenium to click a button in google translate (the From: button) but I'm having trouble doing so. My goal is to select a language from the drop-down menu.

This is, hopefully, the html code for the particular section that I want to click on

```
<div id="gt-sl-gms" class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button je" aria-expanded="false" role="listbox" style="-webkit-user-select: none;" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant=""><div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption">From: English</div><div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown"></div></div>
```

Looking at this it looks like the id is `gt-sl-gms` so I think my selenium code should look like this

```
Open the Browser to google translate
    Open Browser  ${google_translate}  ${browser}

Click From Language button
    Click Button  gt-sl-gms  don't wait
```

However, this doesn't look like a traditional html button so I'm not sure this approach is the one I want.

The first test passes so I know selenium is working but the second test is failing.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use xpath and the keyword "Click Element":

```
Click From Language button
    Click Element    xpath=//div[@id="gt-sl-gms"]    don't wait
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the 'Click Button' keyword of Robot Framework SeleniumLibrary is looking for element locators only inside `<button>` HTML tags. Try using the keyword 'Click Element' instead, which tries to match the locator to any HTML element regardless of their type.

Comment: Actually, it Click Button works on <button> and <input type="button"> elements. Click Element should work in this case.